# Выдает ошибку при попытке получения req.body из post запроса в nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Я пытаюсь вытащить значение req.body.word из пост запроса, но выдает ошибку

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'word' of undefined

не смотря на то, что в корневом файле я прописал `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`

Вот сама форма отправка POST запроса

```
<form action="/createWord" method="post">
        <input
          type="text"
          required
          name="word"
          placeholder="word" />
        <input
          type="text"
          required
          name="translation"
          placeholder="translation"
        />
        <input type="submit" value="addword" />
</form>
```

Так я получаю этот POST запрос

```
router.post("/createWord", async (req, res) => {
  const word = new Word({
    word: req.body.word,
    translation: req.body.translation,
  })

  await word.save()
  res.redirect("/vocabulary")
})
```

Но этот роутер у меня естественно в другом файле, нежели index.js(корневой), я так понимаю это из-за того, что энкодер находиться не в файле с роутерами, как можно это исправить?

Comment: попробуйте в самом роутере добавить `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`

Comment: @nörbörnën блин, точно, сделал так, только с router вместо app - и все заработало, ахах, спасибо)